# Assigning a Datafactory application to an app role

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to run the following command (which I have ran before with no issues) ...

```
# Assign the managed identity access to the app role.
```

New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment `-ObjectId $managedIdentityObjectId`
-Id $appRoleId `-PrincipalId $managedIdentityObjectId`
-ResourceId $serverServicePrincipalObjectId

However, once I insert the values I get the following error ...

New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment: Error occurred while executing NewServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment
Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: Not a valid reference update.
RequestId: 8ad2de7d-8b74-4cd9-b544-3200bb66a763
DateTimeStamp: Mon, 13 Dec 2021 14:04:52 GMT
HttpStatusCode: BadRequest
HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request
HttpResponseStatus: Completed

Anyone have an idea what 'Not a valid reference update' means?

Comment: I should add that the resource I'm trying to assign to an app service role is an Azure Datafactory resource.  I've assigned service principles to roles fine in the past, so not sure if there is a limitation for Datafactory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, connect to the Azure AD.

```
Connect-AzureAD
```

Now use the below command format:

```
New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $ServicePrincipalsID -Id $RoleID -PrincipalId $ServicePrincipalsID -ResourceId $APIservicePrincipalID
```

**Note:** The `ObjectId` and `PrincipalId` are both the MSI-generated service principal's id. `Id` is the id of the role. `ResourceId` is the id for the API service principal.

Answer (score 0):

I've realised where I was going wrong.  My '-ID' (app role id) and '-PrincipallID' values were incorrect (the wrong way round!).  This is all working now.